# Full screen browsing with javascript using setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, fullscreen

I have a page with an iframe that should be updated every 5 minutes.

for this I used the following javascript code

```
var auto 
auto = self.setInterval(function(){refresh()}, 300000);
function refresh()
{
    var iframe = document.getElementById('report');
    iframe.src = iframe.src;

}
```

But now I want to ensure that I am always in full screen

I find in google the following code:

```
function full() {
                var
                      el = document.documentElement
                    , rfs =
                           el.requestFullScreen
                        || el.webkitRequestFullScreen
                        || el.mozRequestFullScreen
                ;
                rfs.call(el);
            };
```

it works fine if I call from a button

but does not work if I call the refresh function from:

```
    var auto
    auto = self.setInterval(function(){clicar()}, 300000);                                  
    function full() {
        var
              el = document.documentElement
            , rfs =
                   el.requestFullScreen
                || el.webkitRequestFullScreen
                || el.mozRequestFullScreen
        ;
        rfs.call(el);
    };  
    function clicar()
    {
        full();

        var iframe = document.getElementById('report');
        iframe.src = iframe.src;

    }
```

The browser returns no error just does not get full screen.

Any idea?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793550/javscript-full-screen-exits-when-user-navigates-around-site?rq=1

Comment: When you call the refresh function, emulate a button click to trigger full screen mode - i've added it as a comment as i don't know if it'll work, just a suggestion

Comment: Emulate the button does not work because it was not the user calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to full screen is a potential security problem, and as such usually has to be tied to a user event (like clicking a button) to be actioned. In this case you wouldn't be able to switch to full screen from a `setInterval` event. There are other reasons why a switch to full screen might fail.

Firefox specifically will log a message to the error console if the switch to full screen fails. Both Firefox and Chrome have opt-in switches that might allow this.

From the MDN page on this:

> It's not guaranteed that you'll be able to switch into fullscreen mode. For example, `<iframe>` elements have the mozallowfullscreen attribute (webkitallowfullscreen, etc) in order to opt-in to allowing their content to be displayed in fullscreen mode.

See the [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Using_fullscreen_mode) on MDN for more details

Answer (score 1):

Oddly current Chrome tells me the same and refuses to start my video in fullscreen if and only if a setInterval (that has nothing todo with the requestFullscreen call) ran in the last 750ms before the call or so.

```
function loop() {
    /* code */
}
setInterval(loop, 1000);
```

So this would lead to refused fullscreen requests in about 8 to 10 cases.

But:

```
function loop() {
    /* code */
    setTimeout(loop, 1000);
}
setTimeout(loop, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to invoke fullscreen without a user input, for example a click.  That's why your function works when called on a button but not a timeout.

I believe this is a browser security issue.  See here for more info https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Reviews/Firefox10/CodeEditor/FullScreenAPI

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with full screen api.

but you can set the `height` and `width` of `iframe` equal to client window in each of your refresh call.